# Закрытие окна в bat файле

Tags: windows, планировщик-задач

Написал bat включение видео и потом создал задачу в планировщике заданий windows 10. Почему то в конце, окно моего видео не закрывается. Также и с презентацией прописанной в bat. 
Какую команду в конце bat файла написать для закрытия окна

Comment: *Почему то в конце, окно моего видео не закрывается.* А почему оно должно закрываться? Читайте параметры вашего плеера, если он умеет закрывать окно по окончанию ролика - то закроет (добавьте нужные параметры, и параметры можно указать прямо в планировщике и не делать батник вообще), если не умеет - то... танцы с бубном - допитать в батник `pause` или `timeout` и длинну ролика в секундах, а потом `taskkill`. Проще малыми силами - никак.

Comment: А в планировщике нет параметра на тему закрывать окно после работы джоба?